# Binding keyboard keys to widgets using events

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, key-bindings

When I tried to bind the keys and started the script the key pressed autotomaticly.
How can I use the event to **wait** for the  key or the submit button to be pressed?

I get this error when running:
[image: Error]

```
import tkinter.scrolledtext as scrolledtext
import multiprocessing as mp
from threading import Lock
import subprocess as sub
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import shutil
import signal
import time
import sys
import os
import io


class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # self.geometry("860x528")
        self.title("GUI Project")
        self.resizable(0, 0)

        menu = tk.Frame(self, relief="solid")
        container = tk.Frame(self, relief="solid", bg="purple")

        menu.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=True)

        menu.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(6, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=2)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=2)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=2)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(5, weight=2)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(6, weight=2)

        self.frames = ["Menu", "CmdCli", "FutureFeature", "FutureFeature2", "FutureFeature3"]

        self.frames[0] = Menu(parent=menu, controller=self)
        self.frames[1] = CmdCli(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[2] = FutureFeature(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[3] = FutureFeature2(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[4] = FutureFeature3(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames[0].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[1].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[2].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[3].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[4].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(1)

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        print(frame)
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


class Menu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="black")
        self.controller = controller

        ping_test_button = tk.Button(self, text="CLI CMD", bg="skyblue1", pady=30,
                                     command=lambda: controller.show_frame(1))
        future_feature1_button = tk.Button(self, text="FutureFeature", bg="dark violet", pady=30,
                                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(2))
        future_feature2_button = tk.Button(self, text="FutureFeature2", bg="pale goldenrod", pady=30,
                                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(3))
        future_feature3_button = tk.Button(self, text="FutureFeature3", bg="green", pady=30,
                                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(4))
        app_exit = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", bg="gray40", pady=30,
                             command=lambda: self.terminate())

        ping_test_button.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        future_feature1_button.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        future_feature2_button.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        future_feature3_button.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        app_exit.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    @staticmethod
    def terminate():

        while True:
            path = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/desktop/Gui-Skeleton'

            try:
                shutil.rmtree(path)
                exit()
            except OSError as err:
                print(f"Error Deleting tmp folder! {err}")
                exit()


class CmdCli(tk.Frame):

    file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/default.txt'
    newfile = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/Gui-Skeleton/default-tmp.txt'
    lastfile = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/logger.txt'

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="skyblue1")
        self.controller = controller

        self.command_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter Command : ", padx=7, pady=5, bg="skyblue1")
        self.command_input_box = tk.Entry(self)
        self.command_input_box.bind(signal., self.thread_handler(self.command_input_box.get()))

        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", width=10, height=1,
                                       command=lambda: self.thread_handler(self.command_input_box.get()))
        self.clear_field_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear Field", width=10, padx=2,
                                            command=lambda: self.clear_boxes(self.command_input_box))
        self.clear_file_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear File", width=10,
                                           command=lambda:
                                           open(self.lastfile, 'w+').close())
        self.clear_window_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear Window", width=10,
                                             command=lambda: self.clean_window())
        self.stop_button = tk.Button(self, text="Stop", padx=20, command=lambda: self.stop_process())

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=20, weight=0)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, minsize=20, weight=2)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, minsize=5, weight=3)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(3, minsize=20, weight=2)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=50, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, minsize=20, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, minsize=30, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3, minsize=10, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(4, minsize=10, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(5, minsize=10, weight=0)

        self.command_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.command_input_box.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.clear_window_button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.clear_file_button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="n")
        self.clear_field_button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="e")
        self.submit_button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="se")
        self.stop_button.place(x=510, y=106)

        self.text_widget()

    def clear_files(self):
        open(self.file, 'w+').close()

    def text_widget(self):

        self.text_window = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self, bg="slategray1")
        self.text_window.insert(tk.END, "")
        self.text_window.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.text_window.grid(row=5, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky="nsew")
```

..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or stack traces.

Comment: is that better?

Comment: Have you tried using lambda? Like this: ```self.url_input_box.bind("<Return>", lambda: self.thread_handler(self.url_input_box.get()))```?

Comment: yeah i get an Error: TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Is it better? No, it's not. There's a ton of unrelated code.  You're asking about how to wait for a button to be clicked. You don't need multiple threads and 300 lines to illustrate the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: I posted the relevant code earlier and the full code under that.

Comment: The callback of `bind` expects a argument, the event object.  So should be `self.url_input_box.bind("<Return>", lambda e: ...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 bingo once again! how long did it take you to get to the level you're at?

Answer (score 0):

By changing the 'lambda' to 'lambda e:' that waits for expression.

```
class CmdCli(tk.Frame):

    file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/default.txt'
    newfile = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/Gui-Skeleton/default-tmp.txt'
    lastfile = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/logger.txt'

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="skyblue1")
        self.controller = controller

        self.command_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter Command : ", padx=7, pady=5, bg="skyblue1")
        self.command_input_box = tk.Entry(self)
        self.command_input_box.bind('<Return>', lambda e: self.thread_handler(self.command_input_box.get()))

        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", width=10, height=1,
                                       command=lambda: self.thread_handler(self.command_input_box.get()))
        self.clear_field_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear Field", width=10, padx=2,
                                            command=lambda: self.clear_boxes(self.command_input_box))
        self.clear_file_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear File", width=10,
                                           command=lambda:
                                           open(self.lastfile, 'w+').close())
        self.clear_window_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear Window", width=10,
                                             command=lambda: self.clean_window())
        self.stop_button = tk.Button(self, text="Stop", padx=20, command=lambda: self.stop_process())

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=20, weight=0)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, minsize=20, weight=2)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, minsize=5, weight=3)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(3, minsize=20, weight=2)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=50, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, minsize=20, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, minsize=30, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3, minsize=10, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(4, minsize=10, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(5, minsize=10, weight=0)

        self.command_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.command_input_box.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.clear_window_button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.clear_file_button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="n")
        self.clear_field_button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="e")
        self.submit_button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="se")
        self.stop_button.place(x=510, y=106)
```

Thanks again acw1668!